# Wrong output if no such file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find out no.of files of particular type. If file exists then this script works fine, else for loop executed once(which is not expected to run).

```
echo "Checking for text files..."

j=0
for i in *.txt;
do
echo $i;
j=`expr $j + 1`;
done

if [ $j -ge 0 ];then
echo "No.of Text files:"$j
else
echo "No Text files."
fi
```

There may be some other way to same thing like `ls *.txt |xargs ...`. But as a newbie I would like to know the problem in the posted script. I request you to share your knowledge in this regard.

Comment: Do you really need a *script* to do that?  Wouldn't something like `ls -l *.txt | wc -l` work?

Comment: Im just started learning shell scripts. Anyway I will try this too. But what could be the issue in this script??

Comment: One stylistic tip: you don't need semicolon at the end of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no matching file for the pattern `*.txt`, it's interpreted as a literal string `"*.txt"`. That's why your loop runs at least once.

There are several ways to deal with this issue. You could add a check for the presence of matching files like this:

```
if ls *.txt >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  for i in *.txt; do
    ...
  done
fi
```

Depending on what you want to do inside the loop, you could also use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" | while read i; do
  ...
done
```

Some things, however, won't work with this construct (like incrementing `$j`), because the `while` loop runs in a subshell, so all changes to `$j` are lost when the subshell exits (i.e. the loop terminates).

As a side note: I'd change the incrementation of `$j` from `` j=`expr $j + 1` `` to `((j++))`.

Comment: Parsing the output of `find` is not a good idea in general. Also here, the `while` loop will be executed in a subshell, so if you do `((++j))` in there, it won't be seen after the subshell exits.

Comment: I'm not parsing `find` output here, just reading it line-by-line. What's wrong with that? You're right about incrementing `$j`, though. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's wrong if a filename contains a linebreak. Try: `touch $'a file with\nline breaks\nin\its\name.txt'` and you'll have some surprises! Moreover, because `read` discards spaces at the beginning and ending of the line, you can have problems in some cases. There are good habits and there are bad habits. Most bad habits might work 99.9% of the time, but when they break, it's terrible.

Comment: Reading the output of `find` line by line is actually what I call parsing its output. But I might be wrong. `:)`

Comment: I'd consider it a pretty bad habit to have filenames containing line feeds or starting/ending with whitespace.

Comment: `if [ -f *.txt ]` fails with "too many arguments" if you have multiple files matching "*.txt", so your first way doesn't really work.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the heads up. I changed my answer to use the return code of `ls` instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are no problems in your script, really, except that it could be written in a better style, using modern builtins and except that it fails if there are no text files, see below.

```
echo "Checking for text files..."

j=0
for i in *.txt; do
    echo "$i"
    ((++j))
done

if ((j!=0)); then
    echo "No. of Text files: $j"
else
    echo "No Text files."
fi
```

When using globbing, it's *always* a good practice to use either `nullglob` of `failglob`.

- `failglob` will raise an error if the glob can't be expanded,
- `nullglob` will just expand to nothing if there are no suitable expansions.

without these, `*.txt` will expand to `*.txt` (verbatim) if there are no suitable expansions, which is exactly what you want to avoid!

In your case, just put

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

at the top of your script and you're done!

Now a possible way to count the number of `*.txt` files could be:

```
shopt -s nullglob
a=(*.txt)
echo "There are ${#a[@]} text files"
```

---

What is this fuss about `nullglob` and `failglob`?

Let's go in a scratch directory:

```
$ mkdir scratch; cd scratch
$ # this dir is empty
$ echo *.txt
*.txt
$
```

because the glob has no suitable expansion there. Now:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo *.txt

$
```

because of the `nullglob`. Now we'll unset `nullglob` and set `failglob`:

```
$ shopt -u nullglob
$ shopt -s failglob
$ echo *.txt
bash: no match: *.txt
$
```

Get it?

The bottom line is: *Each time you're using globbing in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), use `failglob` or `nullglob` to make your scripts more robust.*

As a tongue in the cheek bottom line: *Each time you use globbing without `failglob` or `nullglob`, God kills a kitten.*

If you want more information about `shopt` and shell optional behaviour, please referer to [The Shopt Builtin section in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

Comment: +1 Great your's also works fine. But I didnt get nullglob stuffs. Anyway will learn. :)

Comment: @Jeyaram see my edit, tried to clarify `nullglob` and `failglob`.

Comment: so these are bash variable. Interesting. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jeyaram No, not [tag:bash] variables. See [the shopt builtin in the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

Comment: Here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-check-for-any-mp3-files-in-directory/  it is referred as special bash variables. That why I mentioned as bash variables. Anyway I will refer the link.